# How to pass the entire list of id in params?

Tags: java, android, list, android-arrayadapter

I am getting a response in this list retailers object.

```
     List<Retailers> retailers;
```

Say for eg: `retailers.getId()` returns `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` in response and this works fine.

Now I need to store this in another `List` and pass it in params. But only first value `1` is getting stored in all case.
Below is my code for this

```
   List<RoutePlanDayRequests> routePlanDayRequests = new ArrayList<RoutePlanDayRequests>();
                RoutePlanDayRequests requests = new RoutePlanDayRequests();
                for(int i= 0; i<retailers.size();i++){ //retailers is already having datas.
                    Log.e("retailers",retailers.get(i).getId()); //here i am getting 1,2,3,4,5
                    requests.setPartnerId(retailers.get(i).getId());
                    routePlanDayRequests.add(requests); //but while storing i get only 1. 
                    updateServiceList(AppUtils.getMsisdn(mSharedPreferences), routePlanDayRequests);
                }
```

Output Response:

> [{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"1"},{"Id:"1"},{"Id":"1},{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"1"}]

Instead it should get all elements (`1,2,3,4,5` from `retailers.getId`) and pass it in params.
Anybody has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: you need `RoutePlanDayRequests requests = new RoutePlanDayRequests();` inside your loop

Comment: Do you know the difference between "pass by reference" and "pass by value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create `RoutePlanDayRequests` in the loop and send all collected data at the end (outside of the loop) to the `updateService`

```
List<RoutePlanDayRequests> routePlanDayRequests = new ArrayList<RoutePlanDayRequests>();
// you can use the simpler syntax of the for-loop
for(Retailer retailer : retailers) {
    // create the requests object in the loop
    RoutePlanDayRequests requests = new RoutePlanDayRequests();
    Log.e("retailers",retailer.getId());
    requests.setPartnerId(retailers.get(i).getId());
    routePlanDayRequests.add(requests);
}
// call the service outside of the loop
updateServiceList(AppUtils.getMsisdn(mSharedPreferences), routePlanDayRequests);
}
```